# Developer Portal ID in xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

My Apple Developer Account is on multiple teams and that is causing a problem in regards to getting the xcodebuild to run.

Here is the command that I am running.

`xcodebuild -workspace <name>.xcworkspace -scheme "<my scheme>"`

And the error that I am getting is...

`Error Domain=IDECapabilitiesErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation requires a selected developer portal team."`

I have tried setting the `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` and `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` variables manually, but to no avail. I have also attempted to use the fastlane (with match, sigh, and cert) but that did not work as well. I was wondering if anyone knew a workaround for this situation. By the way, I am running this on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have a provision profile selected in the project that you're trying to build, or perhaps don't have a team selected in one of your targets.

Open the project in Xcode and go into the build settings for the project. Make sure that you've got a developer profile selected for both the debug and release cases. Then select each of the build targets in the project and make sure that you've got a team, provision profile, and developer certificate selected. (If you've turned on automatic signing, you just need to select the team, and Xcode will take care of the others.)

Those settings are saved in the project file and will remain in effect when you build with `xcodebuild`.